# Text Extraction and Text recognition

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Starting from text I'd like to be able to identify specific informations.

Example :

Input texts : "The invoice number is 18", "Inv : 75", "Inv N. : 84"

Identified invoice numbers : "18", "75", "84"

The concrete problem is I have a lot of documents containing lots of this information and I would like to use an algorithm to identify and extract various type of fields.

I thought that in theory I'll use some kind of framework / algorithm, input all of my documents and train the algorithm by approving or not the results, but I don't know where to start.

I looked into deep learning for unstructured text, machine learning, Stanford NER, Named Entity Recognition as a general concept etc.

I would appreciate some guidance on where to start implementing such a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Is this just a regex for numbers?

Comment: @Sycorax no as I don't know in advance what kind of text will surround the invoice number. My assumption was if I train the algorithm / AI with enough data, it'll be able to get something for a case that it was not exposed to before. For example after training with the three case above, I assume it'd get the number out of "Invoice N. : 98"

Comment: @Bdloul regex expressions can be quite general, too, so they can also detect new stuff. And deep learning NLP/NER can/will make mistakes, too. The question is, whether just writing down a few regex rules, which can easily be improved as you go along, maybe much easier than developing a DLL NLP concept. And improving regex to be able to deal with a new case is much easier than improving a deep NN. Regexes are so easy, I would even suggest to do both and then compare. My money is on the regex solution.

Comment: @Bdloul From what you've described, a regex for numbers alone would still find "98" in "Invoice N. : 98." If you want something more general, you could develop a regex pattern for a more complex expression. Or you could spend that time trying to train some kind of a model. In either case, you'll need to consider which is the better use of your time and which solution is more likely to have a favorable error tradeoff.